# Returning booleans from query results

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is retrieving marks and messages from my database. Provided with a userToken, I need to find every message that a user has voted on to be returned as a boolean. I want to query all messages and get a list of which ones have been voted on by a specific user and which ones have not. For the ones that have been voted on, I want a truthy boolean value returned. For the ones that have not, I want a falsey boolean value to be returned. My biggest challenge is I need to add it to the query I am already using to retrieve marks and messages; but I am not sure how to do that because this query is already so huge.

**Query**

```
var query = ([
  'SELECT',
  'marks.*,',
  'comments.commentString,',
  'COUNT(votes.id)',
  'FROM comments',
  'LEFT JOIN marks ON marks.commentId = comments.id',
  'LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.commentId = comments.id',
  'WHERE comments.messageId = ?',
  'GROUP BY comments.id'
]).join(' ');

var params = [userData.messageId];
```

**Schema**

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS uncovery;
CREATE DATABASE uncovery;

SET foreign_key_checks=0;

USE uncovery;

CREATE TABLE marks (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  x float(10, 6),
  y float(10, 6),
  z float(10, 6),
  timestamp timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  messageId int(5) NULL,
  commentId int(5) NULL,
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES comments(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  messageString text,
  image VARCHAR(255),
  score int(5) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE comments (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  commentString text,
  messageId int(5),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id)
);

CREATE TABLE votes (
  id int(5) AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  userToken VARCHAR(255),
  messageId int(5) NULL,
  commentId int(5) NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (userToken) REFERENCES users(token),
  FOREIGN KEY (messageId) REFERENCES messages(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (commentId) REFERENCES comments(id),
  UNIQUE KEY (userToken, messageId),
  UNIQUE KEY (userToken, commentId)
);

CREATE TABLE users (
  token VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(token),
  total_votes int(5) DEFAULT 0
);

-- If a message does not have a userToken then this will not work
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER vote_increment AFTER INSERT ON votes
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET users.total_votes = (users.total_votes + 1) WHERE users.token = 
      (SELECT userToken FROM messages WHERE id = NEW.messageId);
  END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

EDIT:

**Overview of System**

This database schema is designed for a mobile chat network. Users have the ability to see messages within a certain range from their current location. Each mark indicates the location of a message. A message is what contains the text left by a user at a given location. And a comment is a reply to any given message. Additionally, users have the ability to vote on specific messages they like. Voting works great, but the problem we are having is determining if a message has been voted on yet or not. We need to know if a message has been voted on so the 'vote' button the mobile phone will be highlighted. My UI guy wants a boolean on the mark object (which is currently being retrieved as a consequence of the query I posted above) which indicates whether or not a specific message has been voted on.

**Overview of Query**

The above query was designed to retrieve all the marks and their associated comments, votes, and messages provided that a users coordinates (Which are provided as parameters to the query) are within a certain range of a mark. This query retrieves many mark objects, not just one.

What I want is in addition to the marks and their related content to be retrieved within each object, is for a boolean to also be retrieved which indicates whether or not the message that is the foreign key to the provided message has been voted on by the user.

Comment: can you add some sample data? and your two queries seem to be at crossed purposes - one is to tally the number of votes for a message, and the other is to see what messages a user has and has not voted on.

Comment: Would you suggest creating a separate query for this? The only reason I wanted to do it all in one query is because my front end guy wants a series of mark objects with that boolean value included in each mark object. I could do a separate query to generate the boolean values though and then just decorate the objects with that value after though.

What format should I display sample data in? Do you want me to just display my tables filled with data? Sorry I am new to MySQL.

Comment: it's just the way you've described it - the query you've shown above gets details about a specific message. What you're asking for is details about all messages for a specific user.  I guess i'm just having difficulty visualising what you're looking for. Marks seems to be some sort of coordinate system, that lets users comment on them and/or leave messages there? are you saying for a specific mark, you want to know if a specific user has voted on it? could you add a basic description of the system to the question?

Comment: I just added additional information

Comment: I figured it all out. Thanks!

Comment: you should put your solution in as an answer